# How to find and replace an items in a ComboBox

Tags: c++, combobox, c++builder

In C++ Builder XE8, I'm using the following methods to insert an item into a ComboBox:

```
MyComboBox->Items->BeginUpdate();
MyComboBox->Items->Insert(0, "Title");
MyComboBox->Items->Insert(1, "Google");
MyComboBox->Items->Insert(2, "Yahoo");
MyComboBox->Items->Insert(3, "127.0.0.1");
MyComboBox->ItemIndex = 0;
MyComboBox->Items->EndUpdate();
```

I want to know how to replace the 3rd item, 127.0.0.1, to "xxx.0.0.1". I've tried using `StringReplace()`, but no luck.

Comment: "*I've tried using stringreplace, but no luck*" - for future reference, whenever you say that something does not work, always show what you actually tried that is not working.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your advice. its very useful for me in order to discuss with a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your example should be using `Add()` instead of `Insert()` (and a `try/__finally` block or RAII wrapper, in case an exception is thrown):

```
MyComboBox->Items->BeginUpdate();
try {
    MyComboBox->Items->Add("Title");
    MyComboBox->Items->Add("Google");
    MyComboBox->Items->Add("Yahoo");
    MyComboBox->Items->Add("127.0.0.1");
    MyComboBox->ItemIndex = 0;
}
__finally {
    MyComboBox->Items->EndUpdate();
}
```

Now, with that said, if you know the item you want to change is always the fourth item, then simply update it directly:

```
MyComboBox->Items->Strings[3] = "xxx.0.0.1";
```

If you need to search for it, use `IndexOf()`:

```
int index = MyComboBox->Items->IndexOf("127.0.0.1");
if (index != -1)
    MyComboBox->Items->Strings[index] = "xxx.0.0.1";
```

Comment: Again, thanks very much. All the way you tell it has worked very well.